# How to create a 2d array in Unity using Visual Scripting?

Tags: unity, array

Found some good tutorials on how to create 2-dimensional arrays in Unity:
https://owlcation.com/stem/Using-Single-and-Multi-Dimensional-Arrays-in-C-and-Unity3D

Anyone know if this is also supported in Unity's Visual Scripting?

Comment: Have you tried to see if it is supported? 2-dimensional arrays are kinda basic, it would be more strange if they would not be.

Comment: @zibelas I did try... I do see Dictionaries and Lists in the Visual Scription options, but don't see Arrays at all.  But I may be missing it, so thought I'd ask here!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by making your own class.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Array2D<T>
{
    [SerializeField]
    int _width;

    [SerializeField]
    T[] _data;

    public void Initialize(int width, int height) {
        this._width = width;
        int size = width * height;
        _data = new T[size];
    }

    public T Get(int x, int y) {
        return _data[GetIndex(x, y)];
    }

    public void Set(int x, int y, T value) {
        int index = x * _width + y;
        _data[GetIndex(x, y)] = value;
    }

    int GetIndex(int x, int y) => x * _width + y;
}
```

(I've elided bounds-checking here, so if you try to index outside the dimensions of the array you'll generate an exception or access the wrong item. You can avoid this by structuring your graphs/code to ensure your accesses are always in bounds, or adding your own bounds-checking and fallback behaviour in the methods above)

Unity Visual Scripting won't pick up on custom generics on its own, so you need to stamp out a specialization of this class for each contained type you want to work with:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Array2DInt : Array2D<int> {}
```

Then you can go to Project Settings > Visual Scripting and add your new type to the Types section, then click "Regenerate Nodes" to produce nodes supporting this type.

Then you can make variables of this new type, initialize them to a blank array of your chosen dimensions, and get or set values at any coordinates within that range:

[image: Demo of the new node in use]

This creates a new 5x5 grid of zeros, fetches the value at (1, 3), which is zero, adds one to it, and assigns it back to slot (1, 3) in the grid.

(Adding a custom property drawer to give a nicer interface for inspecting/editing this type is left as an exercise for the reader )